# cordova-plugin-crop {message: 'Error on cropping', code: '404'}

Tags: ionic-framework

I have been using this plugin and when I try to upload an image from gallery and crop it it gives me error. {message: 'Error on cropping', code: '404'}

following this tutorial https://enappd.com/blog/how-to-add-image-cropper-in-ionic-apps/149/

```
pickImage(sourceType) {
  const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  sourceType: sourceType,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}
 this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
  // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
  // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
  // let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  this.cropImage(imageData)
 }, (err) => {
  // Handle error
  });
 }



 cropImage(fileUrl) {
  this.crop.crop(fileUrl, { quality:100, toSize: 480 })
  .then(
  newPath => {
   this.showCroppedImage(newPath.split('?')[0])
  },
   error => {
   alert('Error cropping image' + error);
   console.log('Error cropping image :' , error)
  }
  );
 }

 showCroppedImage(ImagePath) {
  this.isLoading = true;
   var copyPath = ImagePath;
   var splitPath = copyPath.split('/');
   var imageName = splitPath[splitPath.length - 1];
   var filePath = ImagePath.split(imageName)[0];

  this.file.readAsDataURL(filePath, imageName).then(base64 => {
  this.croppedImagepath = base64;
  this.isLoading = false;
  }, error => {
  alert('Error in showing image' + error);
  this.isLoading = false;
  });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey i implemented the same i have faced no such error

```
 pickImage(sourceType) {
      const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: sourceType,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }
     this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
      // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
      // let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.cropImage(imageData)
     }, (err) => {
      });
     }
     cropImage(fileUrl) {
      this.crop.crop(fileUrl, { quality:100 })
      .then(
      newPath => {
       this.showCroppedImage(newPath.split('?')[0])
      },
       error => {
       alert('Error cropping image' + error);
       console.log('Error cropping image :' , error)
      }
      );
     }
     showCroppedImage(ImagePath) {
       var copyPath = ImagePath;
       var splitPath = copyPath.split('/');
       var imageName = splitPath[splitPath.length - 1];
       var filePath = ImagePath.split(imageName)[0];
    
      this.file.readAsDataURL(filePath, imageName).then(base64 => {
      this.croppedImagepath = base64;
      }, error => {
      alert('Error in showing image' + error);
      });
      }
`
also check my git repo(https://github.com/sai7135/CropImageApp.git) which is working justfine
```